# Why does `|=` seem to mutate a `set` when the long form does not?

Tags: python, set

Alright, I need someone who knows Python better than I do to explain this to me

```
>>> x = set()
>>> y = x
>>> x = x | set([1])
>>> x
{1}
>>> y
set()
```

Ok, great, as expected, the `|` operation creates a new set [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.union) and assigns it to `x`. `y` still points to the original (empty) `set`

So then this is just a shorthand right?

```
>>> x = set()
>>> y = x
>>> x |= set([1])
```

I expect the same results

```
>>> x
{1}
>>> y
{1}
```

WTF!? Is this...documented or...what?

Comment: Afaik, most compound operators are mutating on most collections.

Comment: Just a little bit lower: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.update

Comment: The augmented assignment operators work in-place, if possible, and is not supposed to be a shorthand for what you might expect.

Comment: See the original proposal when they were added to the language: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/#proposed-semantics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|=` actually calls `update` method, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.update
This is why it's mutating the set

Comment: Ah yes...I see...exactly a page of scrolling lower so you don't see it when browsing the docs. Making an operator pattern that is typically immutable and work completely different and in a mutable way with a few operators..well this seems like a terrible idea for an API.

Comment: I mean, it's the first time that the `|=` operator is documented, so I'm not sure that's a valid criticism.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this also happens for other mutable types such as lists:

```
>>> x = list('abc')
>>> y = x
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> y
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x += ['d']
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> y
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Turns out that, for augmented assignment expressions, [Python tries to use an in-place operation whenever possible](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> An augmented assignment expression like x += 1 can be rewritten as x = x + 1 to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the augmented version, x is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead.